# ADFS authentication

Tags: adfs

We have a problem we're facing while trying to authenticate with ADFS,

We have two environments (dev and prod), both configured the same way, windows server 2012

In dev everything works fine, but in prod we are getting the following error:

> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   Message: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication
>   scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server
>   was 'Negotiate
>   oXAwbqADCgEBomcEZWBjBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIDAH5UMFKgAwIBBaEDAgEepBEYDzIwMTYwMjAyMTUyOTI2WqUFAgMM8+6mAwIBKakLGwlIUlQuTE9DQUyqGjAYoAMCAQGhETAPGw1TVkMtQURGUy1QUkQy'.
>
> Inner Exception: The target principal name is incorrect

We don't know what to do, we've checked every ADFS configuration and everything looks fine.

Comment: Did you try this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288167

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265975/authentication-issues-with-www-authenticate-negotiate could be Kerberos configured

Answer (score 2):

An SAML trace using SAML tracer (FireFox extension : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) could be useful in your case to decode the SAML Request and Response in order gather more information about your issue.