# Reading authorization response for HTTP AD login

Tags: node.js, http, active-directory, ldap, ntlm

I am trying to implement Active Directory login for my webpage. The webpage is hosted on a Node.js server that can talk to a the AD server via LDAP (so it is not on the same physical machine right now).

To trigger the login request, I send a `401` and `WWW-Authorize: Neogiate` response to a GET request triggered when the page is loaded. This causes Chrome to open a Username/Password dialogue. However when I enter some info and click Submit, I do not see any of the username/password data. Instead I see this   `authorization: 'Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAGNFAAAADw=='` which when decoded is this `NTLMSSP cE`

I am not sure what to do with this token or how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into this error because the server is directing you for implementation and [Protected GSSAPI Negotiation Mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995330(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#http-sso-2_topic1). This is a Microsoft [invention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265975/authentication-issues-with-www-authenticate-negotiate/4514918#4514918) for negotiating a type of authentication to use for Web SSO (single-sign-on):

- either NTLM
- or Kerberos

You need to store this token into the localStorage or cookies.

For example when you get the token from the server you then can save this on localStorage like this:

```
 localStorage.setItem('token', token);
```

Then when you call the API you then have to send this token to the server with the request.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `express-ntlm` which (for maybe the first time in history) worked on the first try